# Need to select a column value based on another column value if its true in sql?

Tags: sql, select, select-query

Table structure

```
id  col1   col2
 1  data1  false
 2  data2  true
```

I tried

```
select id, case col2 when true then col1 from table
```

and it is showing an internal server error. I want to select the col1 from table when the corresponding col2 is true.

Comment: Do you understand that when col2 is false you will still get col1 in output but it's value will be NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably just a simple syntax error in your case statment.
try this..

```
select 
id,
case when col2=1 then col1 else 'some other value' end as computedCaseCol
from table1
```

see: [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61ff4)

Comment: Thanks Mortalus. let me try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that ?

```
select id,col1 from tabe where col2 = 'true'
```

or

```
select id,col1 from tabe where col2 is true
```

??

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg. But i need to select some  other columns and only this column (eg: col1 ) in this way. proper eg: select col3,col4,col5, (case col2  when true then col1)  from table where id=1;